# Windows 7 fresh install won't boot without 2nd harddrive, missing boot partition?

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd, windows-installation, boot-partition

I just tried to upgrade my wife's computer to an SSD for silence and speed.

To do the install I physically added the new SSD to an empty SATA port and then used the Windows 7 install disk to put a fresh copy on the SSD.  During this process I left the original hard drive attached to the system.  My wife then just copied the files she wanted from the old drive to the new SSD.

Yesterday, I removed the old drive and the SSD will not boot.  It appears that the SSD is missing the boot sector altogether.  It is also missing the recovery partition normally seen on Win 7 boot drives.  It appears that the Win7 installer just used the boot loader on the original drive.  I should have disconnected the original drive while I installed Win7 on the new SSD.  Here is my question.

Is there a way for me to fix the SSD to be a stand alone boot drive?

I would rather not start over from the beginning because my wife has the new SSD all set up the way she likes it.

Thanks for any advice.

Pete

Comment: When the pc is booting can you go into the 'boot options' menu and select the SSD?  It is possible that the BIOS does not have the new drive configured as a boot option.

Comment: Yes, when booting I can go into the BIOS boot menu and the SSD is listed.  On the other hand, when I go into setup the SSD does not show up in the boot order list or otherwise.  This is true whether I plug the SSD into an internal SATA port or the eSATA port.  The machine is an old Gateway SFF machine. OS is Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: I should mention that I tried using "bootrec /fixboot" and "bootrec /fixmbr" from the recovery disk command prompt. Also, I looked at the SSD with a partition editor and it is missing the 100MB recovery partition that is usually the first partition on a Windows 7 boot drive.

Comment: When you select the SSD from the boot menu do you receive an error when the system tries to boot to it?

Comment: The machine acts like there is not a bootable drive installed in the computer. It hangs with a bios message saying to put a bootable CD into the machine so it can try again.

Comment: My windows 7 64 bit install does not have any other partitions than the C: drive.  So missing a "Recovery" partition should not be a problem.  This definitely sounds like a boot sector issue.  Did you try the fixboot and fixmbr with the other drive removed and the SSD on the first SATA port?

Comment: Yes, I tried "bootrec /fixboot" and "bootrec /fixmbr" on the SSD with all other drives removed.  There was no effect.  The bios did not see the SSD as a bootable device and asked for the CD to be inserted.  Still, I will try those commands again in case I did something wrong last time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Find out from `diskpart`,`list disk`,`select disk 0`,`list partition`,`select partition #N`,`detail partition` about what drive letter your windows drive has (say C:).

Then, `bcdboot C:\Windows /s C: /f BIOS` to regenerate all boot files.

Comment: @peterdudley good to know. But why not convert to [UEFI](http://superuser.com/a/383180/203254)?

Comment: Be sure to run the command prompt as administrator or you may get: "Failure when attempting to copy boot files."

Answer (score 1):

Attach hard disk again and boot from it.

Open Disk Management - **on SSD mark Windows partition as active** using right-click ->

See which drive letter corresponds to SDD Windows partition. Assume it is D:.

Open administrative command prompt:

1. **bootsect /nt60 ALL /force /mbr**
2. **bcdboot d:\windows /s d:**  (if another drive letter corresponds to SSD Windows partition replace it)

Comment: This also worked for me